# .config file not copied to bin\config folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've created a config file (in a console app) which is in the Config folder, but unlike the other files in this folder (such as appSettings.config) it's not getting copied to the bin\Config folder.

I have referenced it properly in App.config but not getting copied to bin\Config\

What is it I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: Config files has never gone to a 'Config' folder...

Comment: Right click, properties, copy to output folder! Works!

Comment: @leppie if you move App.config to a Config directory that you created in a project and set it to copy on build, it will exist in `bin\Debug\Config`.

Comment: Someone answered the question, but then deleted their answer?!

Comment: @thegunner, I answered, then deleted, then undeleted. I think, that this is bug in my internet connection, sorry

Comment: @Stijn: And what will that achieve?

Comment: @leppie I don't know why one would do it. I just explained how it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should open properties of this file and specify `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`